# Django Channels Websocket hanging - WebSocketProtocol took too long to shut down and was killed

Tags: django, websocket, django-channels, daphne

Environment:

- Ubuntu 16.04.6
- conda 4.12.0
- Apache/2.4.18 (Ubuntu)
- python==3.8.1
- Django==4.0.3
- channels==3.0.5
- asgi-redis==1.4.3
- asgiref==3.4.1
- daphne==3.0.2

I am attempting to create a websocket service that only relays messages from redis to an authenticated user. Users do not communicate with each other, therefore I don't need Channel layers and my understanding is that Channel layers are an entirely optional part of Channels.

I'm simply trying to broadcast messages specific to a user that has been authenticated through custom middleware. I have custom auth middleware that takes an incoming session id and returns the authenticated user dictionary along with a user_id. I'm also attaching this user_id to the scope.

I have elected to route all traffic through daphne via Apache2 using ProxyPass on port 8033. This is preferred since I'm using a single domain for this service.

However, I'm really struggling to maintain a connection to the websocket server, particularly if I refresh the browser. It will work on the first request, and fail after with the following message in journalctl:

```
Application instance <Task pending name='Task-22' coro=<ProtocolTypeRouter.__call__() running at /root/miniconda2/lib/python3.8/site-packages/channels/routing.py:71> wait_for=<Future pending cb=[<TaskWakeupMethWrapper object at 0x7f658c03f670>()]>> for connection <WebSocketProtocol client=['127.0.0.1', 46010] path=b'/ws/userupdates/'> took too long to shut down and was killed.
```

After spending hours on the github for channels, and trying many of the suggestions (particularly found on https://github.com/django/channels/issues/1119), I'm still at a loss. The version of the code below is the best working version so far that at least establishes an initial connection, sends back the connection payload `{"success": true, "user_id": XXXXXX, "message": "Connected"}` and relays all redis messages successfully. **But, if I refresh the browser, or close and reopen, it fails to establish a connection and posts the above journalctl message until I restart apache and daphne.**

My hunch is that I'm not properly disconnecting the consumer or I'm missing proper use of async await. Any thoughts?

#### Relevant apache config

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Connection} Upgrade [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Upgrade} websocket [NC]
RewriteRule /(.*) ws://127.0.0.1:8033/$1 [P,L]

<Location />
    ProxyPass http://127.0.0.1:8033/
    ProxyPassReverse /
</Location>
```

#### app/settings.py

```
[...]
ASGI_APPLICATION = 'app.asgi.application'
ASGI_THREADS = 1000
CHANNEL_LAYERS = {}
[...]
```

#### app/asgi.py

```
import os

from django.core.asgi import get_asgi_application
from django.urls import path
from channels.routing import ProtocolTypeRouter, URLRouter
from channels.security.websocket import AllowedHostsOriginValidator

os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'app.settings')

import websockets.routing
from user.models import UserAuthMiddleware

application = ProtocolTypeRouter({
    'http': get_asgi_application(),
    "websocket": AllowedHostsOriginValidator(
        UserAuthMiddleware(
            URLRouter(websockets.routing.websocket_urlpatterns)
        )
    ),
})
```

#### user/models.py::UserAuthMiddleWare

Pulls user_id from custom authentication layer and attaches user_id to scope.

```
class UserAuthMiddleware(CookieMiddleware):
    def __init__(self, app):
        self.app = app
    async def __call__(self, scope, receive, send):
        # Check this actually has headers. They're a required scope key for HTTP and WS.
        if "headers" not in scope:
            raise UserSessionError(
                "UserAuthMiddleware was passed a scope that did not have a headers key "
                + "(make sure it is only passed HTTP or WebSocket connections)"
            )
        # Go through headers to find the cookie one
        for name, value in scope.get("headers", []):
            if name == b"cookie":
                cookies = parse_cookie(value.decode("latin1"))
                break
        else:
            # No cookie header found - add an empty default.
            cookies = {}

        # now gather user data from session
        try:
            req = HttpRequest()
            req.GET = QueryDict(query_string=scope.get("query_string"))
            setattr(req, 'COOKIES', cookies)
            setattr(req, 'headers', scope.get("headers")),

            session = UserSession(req)
            scope['user_id'] = session.get_user_id()
        except UserSessionError as e:
            raise e

        return await self.app(scope, receive, send)
```

#### websockets/routing.py

```
from django.urls import re_path
from . import consumers

websocket_urlpatterns = [
    re_path(r'ws/userupdates/', consumers.UserUpdatesConsumer.as_asgi())
]
```

#### websockets/consumers.py::UserUpdatesConsumer

```
from channels.generic.websocket import JsonWebsocketConsumer
import json, redis

class UserUpdatesConsumer(JsonWebsocketConsumer):
    def connect(self):
        self.accept()

        self.redis = redis.Redis(host='127.0.0.1', port=6379, db=0, decode_responses=True)
        self.p = self.redis.pubsub()

        if 'user_id' not in self.scope:
            self.send_json({
                'success': False,
                'message': 'No user_id present'
            })
            self.close()
        else:
            self.send_json({
                'success': True,
                'user_id': self.scope['user_id'],
                'message': 'Connected'
            })

            self.p.psubscribe(f"dip_alerts")
            self.p.psubscribe(f"userupdates_{self.scope['user_id']}*")
            for message in self.p.listen():

                if message.get('type') == 'psubscribe' and message.get('data') in [1,2]:
                    continue

                if message.get('channel') == "dip_alerts":
                    self.send_json({
                        "key": "dip_alerts",
                        "event": "dip_alert",
                        "data": json.loads(message.get('data'))
                    })
                else:
                    self.send(message.get('data'))
```